# How do I prevent Dropbox remotely from syncing?

Tags: sync, dropbox

I have dropbox installed on my home computer and on my work computer, but I only want certain folders to be synced. I use the selective syncing option in preferences. But whenever I add a new folder at home to the root directory of my dropbox it adds the folder automatically on my work computer. I then have to manually deselect the folder in the selective syncing option at work.

Is there way to reverse this option i.e to only add folders to the work dropbox if I explicitly add them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dropbox selective sync - is it possible to have new folders created on other devices NOT be automatically added to sync folders on current device?](http://superuser.com/questions/975207/dropbox-selective-sync-is-it-possible-to-have-new-folders-created-on-other-dev)  (Yes, I know that one came later, but it got more discussion and answers.)

Answer (score 0):

#### Short answer

No, it's not possible to prevent Dropbox syncing of folder in the root directory.

#### Long answer

No, it's not possible, but there's a **workaround** that requires a little of organization: you can create at least **two folders**, one for things you want to keep only on your `Work PC` and another for things you want to keep only on your `Home PC`. Things put elsewhere will be synchronized to both PCs.

I do something similar with my photo collection, since I use 3 PCs. Let's call them `Home PC`, `Office PC` and `Laptop PC`.
I want to keep al my photos in `Home PC`, most recent photos on `Laptop PC` (I have a small SSD), and no photos on "Office PC" (don't need them there).

So I created two folders: `Photo Library` and `Recent Photos`. Both of them are synchronized to `Home PC`. On `Laptop PC` I tell Dropbox to sync only `Recent Photos`. On `Office Pc` I don't synchronize neither of them.

This way when I move things from `Recent Photos` to `Photo Library` (I can do it from `Home PC` or from Dropbox web app), they get deleted from `Laptop PC`, even if my laptop is off (actually Dropbox will remove them once it syncs).

I can even put files on `Home PC` and `Laptop PC` from any other device using the web interface or the mobile app.