# Dropbox selective sync - is it possible to have new folders created on other devices NOT be automatically added to sync folders on current device?

Tags: sync, dropbox

For example:

I have the following folders in my Dropbox:

```
Folder1
Folder2
Folder3
```

On **PC1**, I have only the following folders selected in selective sync:

```
Folder1
Folder2
```

`Folder3` does does not sync to this PC as it is omitted in selective sync.

Now on **PC2**, I create a new folder, `Folder4`.

Dropbox automatically adds the folder to the selected sync folders on **PC1**

So I now have on **PC1**:

```
Folder1
Folder2
Folder4 (added automatically to selective sync folders)
```

Is there a way to set up Dropbox so that `Folder4` is ***not*** synced to **PC1** until I explicitly select it in selective sync?

Comment: If I understand your problem (and I'm not sure I do) you can create an empty `Folder4` on **PC2**, and it will propagate to **PC1**. You can now remove it from selective sync on **PC1** and anything you now add to it on **PC2** will not be copied.

Comment: The point is, I don't want to have to remove it from selective sync. I wan't Dropbox on PC1 know that I'm using selective sync, so only sync the folders I have originally specified, and not automatically sync new ones.

Comment: DropBox defaults to syncing new folders. The best I can suggest is to create a folder `NoSync` which you deselect from sync on **PC1** once only, then create any new folders under that if you do not want to sync them. You then move them up a level when you subsequently require to sync them. This puts **PC2** in control of syncing.

Comment: That does sound like a reasonable work around. Would probably end up with everything in the nosync folder!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this, but only with subfolders:

```
Dropbox --> PC1     --> Folder1
                    --> Folder2
        --> PC2     --> Folder3
                    --> Folder4
        --> All PCs --> Folder5
```

So PC1 has selective sync setup to sync `PC1` and `All PCs`, PC2 has selective sync setup to sync `PC2` and `All PCs`.

Therefore if PC2 creates `PC2 --> Folder6` it will not be synced to PC1.

Unfortunately adding a subfolder of a partially synced folder causes any new folders to also sync, so this is the only current way for this to work.

Comment: Yes, I think a solution like this is the way to go. It's a shame, because to me the obvious default behaviour would be having selected a restricted sync set, retain this set until I choose to sync more. I guess there's situations where the opposite is preferable (e.g. for subfolders of folders that I *do* want to sync)

Comment: @gb2d I understand your point, but the default behaviour seems to be the safer one, since it gives you those files locally even if you don't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Other than workarounds with subfolders (e.g. create a "Dropbox" subfolder with everything in it and update your links to point to the deeper nested dropbox), this is not currently supported.

There is a [discussion in Dropbox Forums](https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203996925-How-do-I-exclude-new-folders-from-being-added-to-Selective-Sync-by-default-?page=1#community_comment_205607546) about this issue which may be updated if there is a fix released by Dropbox.